# DetachedInstanceError when creating Pyramid Session with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, zope

I wrote my own implementation of the `ISession` [interface](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/_modules/pyramid/interfaces.html#ISession) of Pyramid which should store the Session in a database. Everything works real nice, but somehow `pyramid_tm` throws up on this. As soon as it is activated it says this:

```
DetachedInstanceError: Instance <Session at 0x38036d0> is not bound to a Session;
attribute refresh operation cannot proceed
```

(Don't get confused here: The `<Session ...>` is the class name for the model, the "... to a Session" most likely refers to SQLAlchemy's Session (which I call `DBSession` to avoid confusion).

I have looked through mailing lists and SO and it seems anytime someone has the problem, they are

- spawning a new thread or
- manually call `transaction.commit()`

I do neither of those things. However, the specialty here is, that my session gets passed around by Pyramid a lot. First I do `DBSession.add(session)` and then `return session`. I can afterwards work with the session, flash new messages etc.

However, it seems once the request finishes, I get this exception. Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/javex/data/Arbeit/libraries/python/web_projects/pyramid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/waitress/channel.py", line 329, in service
    task.service()
  File "/home/javex/data/Arbeit/libraries/python/web_projects/pyramid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/waitress/task.py", line 173, in service
    self.execute()
  File "/home/javex/data/Arbeit/libraries/python/web_projects/pyramid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/waitress/task.py", line 380, in execute
    app_iter = self.channel.server.application(env, start_response)
  File "/home/javex/data/Arbeit/libraries/python/web_projects/pyramid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 251, in __call__
    response = self.invoke_subrequest(request, use_tweens=True)
  File "/home/javex/data/Arbeit/libraries/python/web_projects/pyramid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 231, in invoke_subrequest
    request._process_response_callbacks(response)
  File "/home/javex/data/Arbeit/libraries/python/web_projects/pyramid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/request.py", line 243, in _process_response_callbacks
    callback(self, response)
  File "/home/javex/data/Arbeit/libraries/python/web_projects/pyramid/miniblog/miniblog/models.py", line 218, in _set_cookie
    print("Setting cookie %s with value %s for session with id %s" % (self._cookie_name, self._cookie, self.id))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 168, in __get__
    return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance),dict_)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 451, in get
    value = callable_(passive)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 285, in __call__
    self.manager.deferred_scalar_loader(self, toload)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1668, in _load_scalar_attributes
    (state_str(state)))
DetachedInstanceError: Instance <Session at 0x7f4a1c04e710> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed
```

For this case, I deactivated the debug toolbar. The error gets thrown from there once I activate it. It seems the problem here is accessing the object at any point.

I realize I could try to detach it somehow, but this doesn't seem like the right way as the element couldn't be modified without explicitly adding it to a session again.

So when I don't spawn new threads and I don't explicitly call commit, I guess the transaction is committing before the request is fully gone and afterwards there is again access to it. How do I handle this problem?

Answer (score 5):

I believe what you're seeing here is a quirk to the fact that response callbacks and finished callbacks are actually executed after tweens. They are positioned just between your app's egress, and middleware. `pyramid_tm`, being a tween, is committing the transaction before your response callback executes - causing the error upon later access.

Getting the order of these things correct is difficult. A possibility off the top of my head is to register your own tween **under** `pyramid_tm` that performs a flush on the session, grabs the id, and sets the cookie on the response.

I sympathize with this issue, as anything that happens after the transaction has been committed is a real gray area in Pyramid where it's not always clear that the session should not be touched. I'll make a note to continue thinking about how to improve this workflow for Pyramid in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I looked into the problem and the tween thing seemed like it could solve it. However, I stumpled upon a solution that was a lot easier (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

I first tried with registering a tween and it worked somehow, but the data did not get saved. I then stumpled upon the [SQLAlchemy Event System](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html). I found the [after_commit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.after_commit) event. Using this, I could set up the detaching of the session object after the commit was done by `pyramid_tm`. I think this provides the full fexibility and doesn't impose any requirements on the order.

My final solution:

```
from sqlalchemy.event import listen
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session as SASession
def detach(db_session):
    from pyramid.threadlocal import get_current_request
    request = get_current_request()
    log.debug("Expunging (detaching) session for DBSession")
    db_session.expunge(request.session)
listen(SASession, 'after_commit', detach)
```

Only drawback: It requires calling [get_current_request()](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/threadlocal.html#pyramid.threadlocal.get_current_request) which is discouraged. However, I saw no way of passing the session in any way, as the event gets called by SQLAlchemy. I thought of some ugly wrapping stuff but I think that would have been way to risky and unstable.

Comment: Good solution! You will also have the added benefit that changes to your session will not be stored if there is an exception, because `pyramid_tm` will abort your transaction instead of committing it.

Comment: Sadly, this does not work, because if no commit happens, it will not trigger the event so it will not detach the object afterwards. The problem seems to be more complicated and I probably will go back to tweens, but I still need to do some experimenting